# Register a WebMvcConfigurationSupport at runtime programatically

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to register a SpringMvc configuration `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` class at runtime with my context. Typically, if I didn't have the requirement to do have it registered at runtime I would use the `@Configuration` annotation on the class, but I need to register a particular instance to control some of the overrides at runtime (without using statics).

Looking at the documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html it would seem like I might be able to use a `ConfigurationClassPostProcessor` via the `context.addBeanFactoryPostProcessor()` method to add my instance of the `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` to the context at runtime, but I can't for the life of my get it to work.

Is what I want to do actually possible, and does anyone have an example?

**EDIT**

So I could do something like this:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    public static List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters;

    @Override
    protected void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.addAll(this.converters);
    }
}


WebMvcConfig.converters = //...
AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
context.register(WebMvcConfig.class);
```

But I don't like the use of the statics there and it means I can't use multiple instances of the `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` class at once. (Ie the same code creating multiple web servers)

What I would actually like is something like this:

```
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    private List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters;

    public WebMvcConfig setConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        this.converters = converters;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.addAll(this.converters);
    }
}

AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
context.register((new WebMvcConfig()).setConverters(...));
```

The ultimate idea is that I am building a sort of "web server" builder factory that will quickly throw up a server for me where I only have to give it a few parameters and some controllers (config is taken care of by the factory)....as I find that I am using the same code in alot of projects.

Comment: What is the end goal? What do you want the `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` to do?

Comment: Its a replacement for the `@EnableMvc` annotation. I am using it to configure SpringMvc...but I have logic to control the configuration at runtime based on the member variables of the class which it can get from setters or the constructor (not decided how that is going to work yet). Example would be the message converters.

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail what you want to do? What you're asking for is possible, but not ideal (and may cause a NPE that I just discovered and reported).

Comment: What are you trying to do that forces you to ditch `@EnableMvc` and makes you configure a custom `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` ?

Comment: I apologise, I clearly am not very good at explaining. I hope the edit I've just made with an example makes sense.

Comment: If all you want to do is configure some `HttpConverter` objects, you can use `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.configureMessageConverters`.

Comment: I also suggest that you look into Spring Boot

Comment: @geoand - Unless I am completely missing the point, I don't see how either of those suggestions will help me.

Comment: From the configuration you are showing, you are trying to register some `HttpConverter` objects. That can easily be done without needing to implement a custom `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`. Second, you say that you want to `throw up a web server`. Does that mean that you want to be able to start a web server from code? If so, then you don't need to do all the heavy lifting, and Spring Boot already does all the work for you

Comment: The problem is not registering the converters, I can do that just fine. The issue is that I wish to register an instance of an `@Configuration` class programatically rather than letting the context can for classes with the `@Configuration` annotation and spring creating its own instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not found the answer, but I've found a workaround that I am happy with now:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Autowired
    private WebMvcConfigDetails details;

    @Override
    protected void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.addAll(details.converters);
    }
}
```

The the `WebMvcConfigDetails` need to be added to the context by this:

```
context.addBeanFactoryPostProcessor(new BeanFactoryPostProcessor() {

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        beanFactory.registerSingleton("webMvcConfigDetails", webMvcConfigDetails);
    }});
```

Answer (score 0):

Implementing `WebMvcConfigurer` would register the class that extends `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` (for spring 4+).

So in your case:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private WebMvcConfigDetails details;

    @Override
    protected void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.addAll(details.converters);
    }

   // overrides
}
```